# Referencing a Source Code Listing

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing

I would love my listings to look like this:

[image]

With the references as shown. is this possible? Would I need to use TikZ?

I have done a pretty exhaustive search but can't find out how this was achieved..

I did ask a similar question but had no image reference to hand to articulate exactly how I would like things to look.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: do you want every line numbered (listings will do this, although with a different default style) or just have numbered reference balls on specific lines?

Comment: Hi David, numbered reference balls, this for me is the cleaner way and more intuitive for my intended audience, thanks, ed

Comment: so in that case you need to add markup to the listed source to mark the highlighted lines, assume that's OK...

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285291/55879), which seems pretty relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to synthesize [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285291/55879) for referencing lines of listings with [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50452/55879) making colored, circled numbers. I did have to use TikZ.

Label a line with `(*\codelabel{name}*)` and reference it with `\coderef{name}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\lstset{ 
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    escapeinside={(*}{*)}, % used to set up \codelabel
    frame=tb
}

\newcommand*{\circled}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
            \node[shape=circle,fill=black,draw,inner sep=0.5pt]
            (char) {\footnotesize\textcolor{white}{#1}};}}

\newcounter{codectr}
\newcommand*{\codelabel}[1]{\refstepcounter{codectr}\circled{\arabic{codectr}}
            \label{#1}}
\newcommand*{\coderef}[1]{\circled{\ref{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={\itshape\texttt{type} and \texttt{attribute}
                   statements}]
attribute file_type; (*\codelabel{ft_attr}*)
attribute domain; (*\codelabel{dom_attr}*)

type system_data_file, file_type, data_file_type; (*\codelabel{sfd_type}*)
type untrusted_app, domain; (*\codelabel{untrusted}*)
\end{lstlisting}

Here, the first~\coderef{ft_attr} and second~\coderef{dom_attr} statements
declare the \verb+file_type+ and \verb+domain+ attributes, and the next
statement~\coderef{sfd_type} declares the \verb+system_data_file+

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wish to use the `hyperref` package to make your references into clickable links, this works with that as well.

Comment: Arun, this is simply awesome! Many thanks for your work, it certainly has helped me a great deal.

Comment: @biggerScala No problem; glad to help :)